# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync in terminal

Tags: .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the common mehod:

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
```

to authorize some calls I'm making to Admob API.

In my machine, everything is ok becuase I'm on macos and the browser opens when I need to enter the authentication information.

But, how can I do this in a terminal? The target server will have an ubuntu terminal and no X installed. Should I use oauth2l for this?

Here is the basic code I use to do the initial login:

```
  var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
            
            UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    secrets,
                    new[] {AdMobService.Scope.AdmobReport},
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("Store"));
            
            string temp = await credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
            
            var service = new AdMobService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "MyApp",
            }); 
            
            var accounts = await service.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync();
```

And this the code I will use (not yet tested), to refresh the token:

```
TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse
            {
                RefreshToken = "XXXXX",
            };
            
            var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = secrets,
                Scopes = new[] {AdMobService.Scope.AdmobReport},
                DataStore = new FileDataStore("Store")
            });
            
            var credential = new UserCredential(flow, "user", token);
```

Comment: You cant  the user will need to open the authorization in a web browsers.  If X isnt installed then you will need to look into something like this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device  which i have not tried with .net

Comment: Feature request added for you .[1812](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1812)